# jQuery click function not triggering

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to integrate a bootstrap layout into my angular.js project.
I have added the bootstrap.js and bootstrap.css and the layout custom CSS and JS.
my project have jquery added to it.

The problem that I am facing is that a click handler is not being triggered.
this is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert('ready');
    $('[data-toggle="offcanvas"]').click(function () {
        alert('click');
        $('.row-offcanvas').toggleClass('active')
    });
});
```

a popup with "ready" popups at each page refresh however when i click the button that has the attribute data-toggle="offcanvas" nothing pops up.

I have even tried to ad an id attribute to the button and target the button in jquery as follows with no success:

```
$('#toggleButton').click(....);
```

the button is html looks like the following:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">
        <p class="pull-right visible-xs">
             <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-toggle="offcanvas">Toggle nav</button>
        </p>
```

what seems to be going wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It works me, http://jsfiddle.net/9stRW/. What jQuery version are you using?

Comment: Its working http://jsfiddle.net/dwebexperts/s3qC6/

Comment: could it be that something with angular or mean.io is deregistering the click event?

Comment: It has nothing to do with AngularJS either: http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/bsU6y/

Comment: for what it's worth, after the page is fully loaded, if i enter the following in the browser console the click is handled correctly:

    $('[data-toggle="offcanvas"]').click(function () {
        alert('click');
        $('.row-offcanvas').toggleClass('active')
    });

Comment: @ExpertSystem but that's assuming that OP isn't using one of the numerous ways that angular ajax imports templates. The proper way to do this in angular is within a directive. Fouad...create a demo in [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue) that replicates the problem

Comment: @charlietfl: Indeed :)